# React Material UI Have A Switch Without Any Extra Padding

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to have a Switch component without extra height, width, padding, margin

This is my `Switch` component

```
<Switch
      checked={isSubscriptionStatusActive}
      onChange={onHandleChangeSubscriptionStatus}
      disabled={subscriptionStatus === 'deactive'}
      aria-label="subscribption-status"
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        bar:  classes.bar,
      }}
 >
```

Here is it's styling

```
let style = {
 root: {
 display: 'inline-flex',
 width: 0,
 position: 'relative',
 flexShrink: 0,
 },
 bar: {
  borderRadius: 7,
  display: 'block',
  position: 'absolute',
  width: 34,
  height: 14,
  top: '50%',
  marginTop: -7,
  left: '50%',
  marginLeft: 0,
 },
};
```

### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

https://codesandbox.io/s/x2wom4pm9z 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/x2wom4pm9z

Material UI Issue Filed Here
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9587

Comment: I check the links are working.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Switch doesn't have any "extra" width or height. The whitespace around it is used to render the ripple.

You can disable the ripple with the `disableRipple` prop, and affect the Switch width as you've dicscovered, but digging into the source, unfortunately it isn't currently possible to pass props to SwitchBase which would be needed to affect the IconButton that is used for the switch "thumb".

You could perhaps modify your issue to discuss the posibility of submitting a PR to adress this limitation. We have `xxxProps` props on other components for similar purposes.

PS. You forgot to link from your issue to here, but I found it anyway. :)